# The density function using the euclidean metric, versus using the sup metric

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be Borel (or even open or closed), let $\mathbf{0} = ( 0 , 0)$, and let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $
\mathcal{D}^2_A ( \mathbf{0} ) = \lim_{ \varepsilon \to 0} \frac{ \lambda ( A \cap B^2 ( \mathbf{0} , \varepsilon ))}{ \lambda ( B^2 ( \mathbf{0} , \varepsilon ) )}$ be the density of $\mathbf{0}$ in $A$ computed using the euclidean metric, so that $B^2 ( \mathbf{0} , \varepsilon ) = \{ ( x , y ) \mid x^2 + y^2 < \varepsilon^2 \} $.
Let $\mathcal{D}^\infty_A ( \mathbf{0} )$ be defined similarly, but using the sup metric, so that $B^\infty ( \mathbf{0} , \varepsilon ) = ( - \varepsilon , \varepsilon ) \times ( - \varepsilon , \varepsilon ) $.

It is not hard to construct sets $A$ such that both densities exist and are different, and other examples where both densities exist and are equal.

Suppose $\mathcal{D}^2_A ( \mathbf{0} )$ exists; does $\mathcal{D}^\infty_A ( \mathbf{0} )$ exist as well?

What about the analogous problem in domension $ \geq 3$?

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOF https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301275/metric-density-of-a-set-in-the-plane-with-respect-to-distinct-metrics